# How to search/filter a Grid View using a ComboBox - C# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, combobox

I would like to know how to filter a GridView which I have populated with Data from an Oracle database. On my Web app I have a combo box and a button.

When the user selects an item from the combo box then clicks the button I want the GridView to be filtered by that selection so what only columns for that selection are shown, but I do not know how to do this.

Here is the code I have:

Creation of DataSet:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("myQuery", myCon);
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataView view = new DataView();
GridView1.DataSource = view;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

DropDown method:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = conversion(Convert.toInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I am not sure what code I need to put into the:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TO DO
}
```

Any Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should check out DataTable.Select method, it could help you.

Comment: Why the need for the button? Simply use the combobox selected change event and then implement filters within that.

Comment: could you please share ` conversion()` code with us ?

Comment: I suppose I do not need the button, but I am not sure how to Implement the filters within that would you know how to do that?

I do not have the code for the `conversion()` method, I have since deleted it as I thought it was incorrect